Spring Batch: finish whole writing in the first writer and then start the second writer
I use Spring Batch 4.3.7. Below is a part of my Spring Batch configuration, which, generally, works:
@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<Record> compositeItemWriter() {
    CompositeItemWriter<Record> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(firstWriter(), secondWriter()));
    return compositeItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public Step batch(StaxEventItemReader<Record> reader, ItemProcessor processor, CompositeItemWriter compositeItemWriter, StepExecutionListener secondWriter) {
    SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get("batch")
            .<Record, Record>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(compositeItemWriter);
    // secondWriter from compositeItemWriter added as a listener for invoking beforeStep and afterStep purpose
    simpleStepBuilder.listener(secondWriter);
    return simpleStepBuilder.build();
}

I have noticed, that the execution of writing parts of the Step is like:
1) 10 records handled by the firstWriter
2) 10 records handled by the secondWriter
3) 10 records handled by the firstWriter
4) 10 records handled by the secondWriter
(...)

What I would like to reach is to make firstWriter write all chunks and then secondWriter write all chunks:
1) 10 records handled by the firstWriter
2) 10 records handled by the firstWriter
(...)
7776) 10 records handled by the firstWriter
7777) 10 records handled by the secondWriter
(...)

How can I obtain that?
EDIT 04.06.2024
I tried to split Job into two Steps, having one Writer each (I have made some simplifications):
@Bean
public Step batchOne(StaxEventItemReader<Record> reader, ItemProcessor processor, FirstWriter firstWriter) {
    SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get("batchOne")
            .<Record, Record>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(firstWriter);
    return simpleStepBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public Step batchTwo(SecondWriter secondWriter) {
    SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get("batchTwo")
            .<Record, Record>chunk(10)
            .writer(secondWriter);
    return simpleStepBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public Job job(Step batchOne, Step batchTwo) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(batchOne)
            .next(batchTwo)
            .build();
}

But now I am receiving error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ItemReader must be provided

I have searched Spring Batch library for an implementation of something like "NoOpItemReader", but haven't found yet.
Isn't it possible to pass data from one writer to another like above? Do I have to (re)read the data again for the secondWriter?
How may I handle this?

Taken from the Spring Batch doc of CompositeItemWriter:

Calls a collection of ItemWriters in fixed-order sequence.

It will indeed call your writers in sequence, however, Spring Batch reads, processes and writes your data in chunks. Meaning in your case that it will read 10 records, process these 10 records, write these 10 records with writer 1, write these 10 records with writer 2, proceed to the next chunk and repeat.
I see 2 ways to achieve what you want:

Have a chunk size big enough to process your entire data at once (but you probably don't want that if you have a lot of data)
Split your step in 2 different steps that will work in sequence. The step 1 will read, process and write with writer 1, then step 2 will read the output of step 1, process it, then write it with writer 1.

